# Is a cyclic dependency solved with require?

Tags: perl, module, dependencies, package, circular-dependency

I noticed that I had a cyclic dependency in 2 of my modules. So I did the following:

```
package A::B::ModuleA;  

sub foo {
  my ($class, $params) = @_;  
  # some processing  
  require A::C::ModuleB;  
  my $mb = A::C::ModuleB->new();  
  $mb->bar($params);  
  # some other processing  
}  

1;  

package A::C::ModuleB;  

sub process {  
  my ($class, $input) = @_;  
  # Some processing  
  require A::B::ModuleA;
  my $ma = A::B::ModuleA;
  $ma->submit($input);   
  # some other processing
}
1;
```

So my question is, if the way that I have addressed the cyclic dependency problem via the require inside the function solves any kind of issue that could be a result of such a dependency.

Comment: Doesn't help at all. You basically explicitly created the situation a circular dependency creates unintentionally. There wasn't even a problem to solve in the first place.

Comment: @ikegami: I think you should elaborate that into a solution.

Comment: @Borodin, To what problem would the solution be saying there wasn't a problem to solve before the OP changed his code?

Comment: @ikegami: Some punctuation would help, but that problem could be anything to do with the current edit. But you confuse me as I can see that there have been no edits to this question.

Comment: @Borodin, The OP had code with a compile-time circular reference. He thought this was a problem. (He made some changes, posted them, and asked about them.) I told him he didn't have a problem. You suggested that my comment could be made into a solution. So I asked you: A solution to what???

Comment: @ikegami:So circular dependencies are not a real problem? Because I have read that there are even CPAN modules to detect one

Comment: I already answered that the first time you asked it: More accurately, *your code* has no problem with the circular dependency. You can run into problems if you export or use prototypes, but that's not the case here. There are [ways](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=778639) of addressing those.

Answer (score 3):

For purely object-oriented code, there is no circular dependency problem. You can quite happily have something like:

```
# AAAA.pm
package AAAA;
use strict;
use warnings;
use BBBB;
sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my ($i) = @_;
    bless {
        b => $i > 0 ? BBBB->new($i-1) : $i
    }, $class;
}
1;

# BBBB.pm
package BBBB;
use strict;
use warnings;
use AAAA;
sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my ($i) = @_;
    bless {
        a => $i > 0 ? AAAA->new($i-1) : $i
    }, $class;
}
1;

# script.pl
use strict;
use warnings;
use AAAA;
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper( AAAA->new(4) );
```

Circular dependencies only become an issue if you need do something with a module at compile-time. Exporters are the most common example of this.

Comment: Actually I noticed the issue when compiled with `-c` option where I got the message of double declaration of methods. Using require give a clean `-c`. But I am not clear on what is the issue about compile time you mention. Do you mean that if it compiles I am ok?

Comment: don't compile with perl -c modulefile, compile with `perl -ce'use modulename'` and you won't get the warnings

Comment: @ysth:Now I am confused. So there is no problem with cyclic dependencies? Or what. I lost you guys. I am sorry

Comment: @Jim, More accurately, *your code* has no problem with the circular dependency. You can run into problems if you export or use prototypes, but that's not the case here. There are [ways](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=778639) of addressing those.

Comment: show use your real code and we could tell you.  in general, as tobyink said, pure OO code won't have any problems, whether you use `use` or `require`

Comment: an example of the kind of problem that can arise: http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=322823